Spring Data JPA - Programmatically Create JPA Repository Not Saving Data
Creating a JPA repository "on the fly" does not seem to work for saving entities (with or without transaction management). Yet it works fine for retrieving data. No error is thrown. With SQL debugging enabled, SQL statements are shown for data retrieval but not for saving data.
I know I can use spring annotations to do this, but I need to create the repository on the fly to allow access to multiple databases. Configuring emf, em and transaction manager beans using @Bean is also not suitable, because in my "real" application, only when the saveIt method (below example)  runs, do we know the actual datasource. The datasource can change in realtime depending on various business rules.
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class BasicRestController {

    private final CompanyService databaseService;

    public BasicRestController(CompanyService databaseService) {
        this.databaseService = databaseService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/saveIt")
    public ResponseEntity<String> saveIt() {
        databaseService.saveIt();
        return new ResponseEntity<>("whatever", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/saveItInTx")
    public ResponseEntity<String> saveItInTransaction() {
        databaseService.saveItInTransaction();
        return new ResponseEntity<>("whatever", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/saveItInTxAndFlush")
    public ResponseEntity<String> saveItInTransactionAndFlush() {
        databaseService.saveItInTransactionAndFlush();
        return new ResponseEntity<>("whatever", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}

In the service below, there are 3 public methods:

saveIt() : Saves a company and yet no data is persisted.
saveItInTransaction : Saves a company inside a transaction and yet no data is persisted.
saveItInTransactionAndFlush : Saves a company inside a transaction and flushes - this fails with "jakarta.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress". Somehow the transaction manager is not getting correctly configured even though it was instantiated using the same   EntityManagerFactory instance which created the EntityManager.

@Service
public class CompanyService {

    private final Environment env;
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public CompanyService(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    public void saveIt() {
        CompanyRepository companyRepository = createJpaRepository();
        // This correctly prints "Stupid Company"
        System.out.println("Allegedly saved company: " + companyRepository.save(new Company("Stupid Company")).getName());
        // This list all the companies already in the database - the allegedly saved company is missing!
        companyRepository.findAll().forEach(company -> System.out.println(company.getName()));
    }

    public void saveItInTransaction() {
        TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = createTransactionTemplate();
        transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
            saveIt();
            return null;
        });
    }

    public void saveItInTransactionAndFlush() {
        TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = createTransactionTemplate();
        transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
            CompanyRepository companyRepository = createJpaRepository();
            // This fails with jakarta.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
            companyRepository.saveAndFlush(new Company("Stupid Company"));
            return null;
        });
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void createEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean = createEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf = emfBean.getObject();
    }

    private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean createEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Objects.requireNonNull(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name")));
        emfBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        emfBean.setPackagesToScan("com.crowfoot.crap.model");
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        emfBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
        emfBean.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        emfBean.setPersistenceUnitName("tryItPU");
        emfBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return emfBean;
    }

    private CompanyRepository createJpaRepository() {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        return new JpaRepositoryFactory(em).getRepository(CompanyRepository.class);
    }

    private TransactionTemplate createTransactionTemplate() {
        PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
        return new TransactionTemplate(platformTransactionManager);
    }

}

@Repository
public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company, Integer> {
}

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/comparison_tim_test
    username: someUser
    password: somePassword
    driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        generate_statistics: false
        ddl-auto: none
        naming:
          physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
      open-in-view: false
      # Debug Hql
      show_sql: true
      format_sql: true
logging:
  level:
    root:
    org:
      hibernate:
        cache: debug
        stat: debug
        SQL: debug
        type:
          descriptor:
            sql:
              BasicBinder: TRACE
      springframework:
        data:
          jpa: debug```


Console output: (saveIt or saveItInTransaction) 

*IMPORTANT: NOTICE THAT THERE IS NO SQL STATEMENT LOGGED FOR THE save(company) OPERATION BUT THERE IS FOR THE findAll().* 

2024-07-11T19:41:31.957+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] com.crowfoot.crap.BasicApplication       : Starting BasicApplication using Java 21.0.3 with PID 10098 (/home/tim/projects/java/junk/basicdynamicrepo/target/classes started by tim in /home/tim/projects/java/junk/basicdynamicrepo)
2024-07-11T19:41:31.960+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] com.crowfoot.crap.BasicApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-07-11T19:41:32.414+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-07-11T19:41:32.446+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 27 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interface.
2024-07-11T19:41:32.816+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-07-11T19:41:32.825+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-07-11T19:41:32.826+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.25]
2024-07-11T19:41:32.856+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-07-11T19:41:32.856+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 860 ms
2024-07-11T19:41:32.951+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-07-11T19:41:33.012+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.mariadb.jdbc.Connection@6401188a
2024-07-11T19:41:33.013+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-07-11T19:41:33.049+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-07-11T19:41:33.089+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.5.2.Final
2024-07-11T19:41:33.111+01:00 DEBUG 10098 --- [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : Cannot default RegionFactory based on registered strategies as `[]` RegionFactory strategies were registered
2024-07-11T19:41:33.111+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-07-11T19:41:33.304+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-07-11T19:41:33.859+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-07-11T19:41:33.861+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-07-11T19:41:33.870+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: tryItPU]
2024-07-11T19:41:33.872+01:00 DEBUG 10098 --- [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : Cannot default RegionFactory based on registered strategies as `[]` RegionFactory strategies were registered
2024-07-11T19:41:33.872+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-07-11T19:41:33.902+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-07-11T19:41:33.941+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-07-11T19:41:33.941+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'tryItPU'
2024-07-11T19:41:33.943+01:00 DEBUG 10098 --- [           main] .c.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean : Initializing JpaMetamodelMappingContext…
2024-07-11T19:41:33.951+01:00 DEBUG 10098 --- [           main] .c.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean : Finished initializing JpaMetamodelMappingContext
2024-07-11T19:41:33.990+01:00  WARN 10098 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-07-11T19:41:34.287+01:00 DEBUG 10098 --- [           main] o.h.stat.internal.StatisticsInitiator    : Statistics initialized [enabled=false]
2024-07-11T19:41:34.386+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/'
2024-07-11T19:41:34.393+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [           main] com.crowfoot.crap.BasicApplication       : Started BasicApplication in 2.758 seconds (process running for 3.208)
2024-07-11T19:41:36.488+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-07-11T19:41:36.489+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-07-11T19:41:36.491+01:00  INFO 10098 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2024-07-11T19:41:36.522+01:00 DEBUG 10098 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.stat.internal.StatisticsInitiator    : Statistics initialized [enabled=false]
Allegedly saved company: Stupid Company
2024-07-11T19:41:36.673+01:00 DEBUG 10098 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.id,c1_0.created_at,c1_0.name,c1_0.updated_at from company c1_0
Previously Existing Company

Console output: (saveItInTransactionAndFlush) 

jakarta.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:529) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(SessionImpl.java:2527) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1416) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1411) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:364) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy134.flush(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.flush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:674) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:641) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:354) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:70) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:165) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy140.saveAndFlush(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.crowfoot.crap.service.CompanyService.lambda$saveItInTransactionAndFlush$2(CompanyService.java:57) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at com.crowfoot.crap.service.CompanyService.saveItInTransactionAndFlush(CompanyService.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.crowfoot.crap.controller.BasicRestController.saveItInTransactionAndFlush(BasicRestController.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:904) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]


What about setting the persistence logging level to debug and putting the insert and commit logging in the question for the withTransaction option.

Added console log - I notice that companyRepository.save(...) operation produces NO SQL LOGGING but  companyRepository.findAll() does.

Ok, so the companyRepository.save leaves no trace or evidence. Can you spread the code around the save out a bit by introducing some local vars, debug and go into save() to explore.

What about adding fields for companyRepository  & platformTransactionManager   in CompanyService and moving their creation into createEntityManagerFactory rather than in saveIt & saveItInTransaction respectively. Maybe it is a lifecyle thing - just guessing.

Thanks very much, John, for your efforts to help me  on this. It seems spring does more behind the scenes than I was aware of, when we use @Bean to annotate datasources, entity manager factories and transaction managers, because my manual creation approach gave ne nothing but a headache! I have replied to my own post with a different approach that seems to work better.

Eventually found a different (better?) approach which achieves the desired result. This allows a datasource to be selected when before or during method execution. Using AbstractRoutingDatasource and storing the key to the data source in a ThreadLocal to make it thread-safe gets us there. Saving the data source key determines which data source/entity manager a repository will use when it is invoked.
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class BasicRestController {

    private final CompanyService databaseService;

    public BasicRestController(CompanyService databaseService) {
        this.databaseService = databaseService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/saveIt/{targetDataSourceKey}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> saveIt(@Valid @PathVariable String targetDataSourceKey) {
        databaseService.saveIt(targetDataSourceKey);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("whatever", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/saveItInTx/{targetDataSourceKey}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> saveItInTransaction(@Valid @PathVariable String targetDataSourceKey) {
        CustomRoutingDataSource.setDataSourceKey(targetDataSourceKey);
        databaseService.saveItInTransaction();
        return new ResponseEntity<>("whatever", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}

public class CustomRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> contextHolder = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setDataSourceKey(String key) {
        contextHolder.set(key);
    }

    public static void clearDataSourceKey() {
        contextHolder.remove();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return contextHolder.get();
    }
}


@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    private final Environment environment;

    public DataSourceConfig(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        AbstractRoutingDataSource routingDataSource = new CustomRoutingDataSource();

        Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();
        targetDataSources.put("admin", adminDataSource());
        targetDataSources.put("test", testDataSource());

        routingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
        routingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(adminDataSource());

        return routingDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource adminDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url(environment.getProperty("spring.admin-datasource.url"))
                .username(environment.getProperty("spring.admin-datasource.username"))
                .password(environment.getProperty("spring.admin-datasource.password"))
                .driverClassName(environment.getProperty("spring.admin-datasource.driver-class-name"))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource testDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url(environment.getProperty("spring.test-datasource.url"))
                .username(environment.getProperty("spring.test-datasource.username"))
                .password(environment.getProperty("spring.test-datasource.password"))
                .driverClassName(environment.getProperty("spring.test-datasource.driver-class-name"))
                .build();
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.crowfoot.crap.repository"
)
public class EntityManagerConfig {

    private final Environment environment;

    public EntityManagerConfig(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactoryBuilder entityManagerFactoryBuilder() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", environment.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
        return new EntityManagerFactoryBuilder(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter(), properties, null);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        return entityManagerFactoryBuilder()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.crowfoot.crap.model")
                .persistenceUnit("default")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}

In the saveIt() below, the data source key is set inside the method body. If desired, different keys can be set within the method itself before calling  subsequent repository methods. However, if the repository method is called inside the saveItInTransaction() method body, the data source key must be set before calling the method, because of the @Transaction annotation.
@Service
public class CompanyService {

    private final CompanyRepository companyRepository;

    public CompanyService(CompanyRepository companyRepository) {
        this.companyRepository = companyRepository;
    }

    public void saveIt(String targetDatasourceKey) {
        CustomRoutingDataSource.setDataSourceKey(targetDatasourceKey); // Set target database
        saveToDatabase();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void saveItInTransaction() {
        saveToDatabase();
    }

    private void saveToDatabase() {
        // This correctly prints "Stupid Company"
        System.out.println("Saved company: " + companyRepository.save(new Company("Stupid Company")).getName());
        // This list all the companies already in the database, and also includes the newly saved company
        companyRepository.findAll().forEach(company -> System.out.println(company.getName()));
    }

application.yaml:
spring:
  admin-datasource:
    url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/comparison_tim_admin
    username: someUser
    password: somePassword
    driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
  test-datasource:
    url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/comparison_tim_test
    username: someUser
    password: somePassword
    driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: none
        naming:
          physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect

